# Auto Inject All Services in .net core AutoFac

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, autofac, .net-core-3.0

I have service base class and different subclasses inherit from it how I can inject all services implement this class

```
public abstract class AppService 
{
 public string ServiceName {get;set;}
}
```

and I have other classes

```
public class CountryService:AppService
{
  public list<Countries> getCountryByName(string name){
return ......
}
}

 public class TestService:AppService
    {
      public void Test(){
    return ......
    }
    }
```

How I can auto inject any class inherit from AppService without need to add this class inside StartUp manually

Update*****************

I am using the following to register services in startUp

```
 services.Configure<ServiceConfig>(config =>
            {
                config.Services = new List<ServiceDescriptor>(services);
                config.Path = "/listservices";
            });

            ContainerSetup.InitializeWeb(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), services);
```

and in Services project here is the container Setup :

```
public static IServiceProvider InitializeWeb(Assembly webAssembly, IServiceCollection services) =>
            new AutofacServiceProvider(BaseAutofacInitialization(setupAction =>
            {
                setupAction.Populate(services);
                setupAction.RegisterAssemblyTypes(webAssembly).AsSelf();
            }));

        public static IContainer BaseAutofacInitialization(Action<ContainerBuilder> setupAction = null)
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
        .Where(t => t.BaseType == typeof(AppService))
        .AsSelf();

            setupAction?.Invoke(builder);
            return builder.Build();

        }
```

Still Getting the error 
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type

Answer (score 0):

You can use AutoFacs built in [AssemblyScanning](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/scanning.html#assembly-scanning) for this.

The following is an example that will register all classes that inherit from `AppService` as their concrete type.

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
       .Where(t => t.BaseType == typeof(AppService))
       .AsSelf();
```

This will allow you to resolve `CountryService` or `TestService` from container.

Comment: Itried your solution by I am gotting this expection ( appService in Different project is that change things ? )An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type '

Comment: @AYKHO if it is in a different project try (`builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(AppService).Assembly)`)

Comment: same exception still cannot inject it

Comment: Can you update your question showing how you are trying to resolve the dependency?

Comment: I found my issue that in .net core I change to use Autofac Module 
thanks Fermin